# How to change some values of a pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, random

I have created a pandas df using `np.random.randn`

```
data = np.random.randn(1, 10)
```

The output I am getting

```
[[-0.92408284 -2.61254901  0.95036968  0.81644508 -1.523876   -0.42804606
  -0.74240684 -0.7033438  -2.13962066 -0.62947496]]
```

Now, if I want to change 2/3 values extremely large or small (i.e `0.95036968 into 95.03` and  `-2.13962066 into -213.96`) then what I have to do?

Here, I need the control to the number I want to change (2/3/4) and the changing bounds  (say, +100 to -300) they can change any number randomly.

Expected Output:

```
[[-0.92408284 -2.61254901  95.03  0.81644508 -1.523876   -0.42804606
  -0.74240684 -0.7033438  -213.96 -0.62947496]]
```

Comment: For your sample, what is the output you expect please?

Comment: @Corralien added expected output in the question.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't consider `-2.61254901` rather than `-2.13962066`?

Comment: @Corralien randomly! Not intentionally just for giving an example. Just need to change any (2/3/4) number could change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = np.random.randn(1, 10)

# indexes to change
# (can be random too: `np.random.choice(np.arange(data.size), size=3)`
inds_to_change = [2, 3, 5]

# range of values to consider for the difference
lower, upper = -300, +100

# sampling some differences
diffs = np.random.choice(np.arange(lower, upper), size=len(inds_to_change))

# changing array values
data[:, inds_to_change] += diffs
```

For the given lower & upper range for changes, we use `np.random.choice` to sample some differences to apply. Then we index into the array and add them where indexes are predefined (or can be random, too).

---

sample run:

```
# to see a cleaner output
>>> np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

>>> data = np.random.randn(1, 10)
>>> data

array([[-0.29,  0.11,  1.25, -1.36,  0.1 , -0.05, -0.36, -1.09, -0.35,
         2.59]])

>>> inds_to_change = [2, 3, 5]
>>> lower, upper = -300, +100

>>> diffs = np.random.choice(np.arange(lower, upper), size=len(inds_to_change))
>>> diffs

array([  94, -294,  -19])

>>> data[:, inds_to_change] += diffs
>>> data

array([[  -0.29,    0.11,   95.25, -295.36,    0.1 ,  -19.05,   -0.36,
          -1.09,   -0.35,    2.59]])
```

Comment: Perfect. I question when I am using `np.random.uniform(10, -10, size=10)` I am getting `[ 5.75321779  6.36350066  6.3319098   3.91515514 -0.49512863]` and shape is `(5, )` but for `np.random.randn` I am getting the shape is `(1, 5)`. Is it possible to convert `(1, 5)` into `(5, )`?

Comment: @Opps_0 `np.random.randn(5)`? But you can also chain `.squeeze()` to your `(1, 5)` shaped array to make it shaped `(5,)`.